# How to display multiple images from an API in Flask

Tags: python, api, flask

I'm using Fortnite [API](https://FortniteAPI.com), more specifically the Python [package](https://pypi.org/project/Fortnite-API-com/), to write a Flask web server. I want to retrieve the Shop images and display them on my flask web server. Please note that I am fairly new to Python and Flask.

I've tried using `@app.route("/shop")` and making a for loop to get the pictures, and returning `return item.information` which should give me all of the links to the image (links look like [this](https://fortnite-public-files.theapinetwork.com/image/69f92c8-c6eb43f-2b62061-286862f/item.png)) and print them. I want to display them as images.

Here's what I've tried, I know it doesn't show them as images but I'm really new. The weird thing is, it doesn't even return all of the links.

```
from flask import Flask
from FortniteAPI import Shop

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/shop")
def shop():
    shop = Shop()
    items = shop.get_items()
    for item in items:
        return item.information
```

I expected the output to show images of each item in the shop, yet it only prints one link and no images.

Comment: you can use `return` only once in function - this is how `return` works in all functions and in all languages - so you can do only `return items`. Or use template and then you can use `for` loop in template to get `information` from every item.. Or create list with information and return this list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions can execute `return` only once.

So you can return items

```
items = shop.get_items()
return items
```

Or you can create new list with `information` and return this list

```
items = shop.get_items()
info = [x.information for x in items]
return info
```

---

To display as images you have to use HTML template and `render_template()`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

items = shop.get_items()
info = [x.information for x in items]

return render_template('all_images.html', links=info)
```

And in `'all_images.html'`

```
{% for url in links %}
<img src="{{ url }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

---

Or using `items`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

items = shop.get_items()

return render_template('all_images.html', links=items)
```

And in `'all_images.html'`

```
{% for url in links %}
<img src="{{ url.information }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

---

**EDIT:** it is not popular but you can also generate HTML directly in function

```
items = shop.get_items()

html = ''

for x in items:
    html += '<img src="{}"/>'.format(x.information)

return html
```

Comment: I get an Internal Server Error while using the 'items' method which is second to last. @furas

Comment: try other methods.

Comment: Sorry, I did something wrong. Now I get the following error:

Comment: last line: `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: all_images.html` - you have to create file `all_images.html` and it has to be in subfolder `templates` - Doc: [Rendering Templates](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#rendering-templates)

Comment: I got it working! Thanks @furas. Marking as correct answer.